# nginx reverse proxy to express server inside docker container

Tags: express, docker, nginx

I am having a trouble to proxy_pass my request to my express server inside the docker container.
Here are my setups:

1. Express server inside docker container. I have setup two routes on the express server which is '/' and '/accounts'. The docker file is the same with the one provided in nodejs official website
   The docker is run with command:
   `docker run -p 7777:8000 -d myImage`
2. Nginx configuration to proxy_pass to port 7777. I also have installed lets encrypt in nginx
   The problem is that when i curl localhost:7777 or curl localhost:7777/accounts, it will correctly response the request. But when i am trying to request using my domain (example.com) which i have setup in nginx, it will only response to example.com request.
   In example.com/accounts, it will return '404 not found'.

EDIT:
nginx config (from awnser, deleted the comments, reordered a bit)

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /{
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Can you share your nginx config?

Comment: `   location /{  
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then  
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.  
        proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777;  
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
#       proxy_redirect http:// https://;
#       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
`

Comment: Is your express server in the same container as nginx? I've noticed proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777;, which tries to access localhost on nginx instead of proxy_pass http://service_name_api:api_port;.
If it is, then you can try using upstream and then proxy_pass there.

Comment: my nginx is on the host machine. and express is inside docker container. i expose docker port 8000 and bind it to host machine port 7777. from the host machine, when i curl localhost:7777. it works and it return response from my express server inside the docker